# Apache Replace two connected characters to one in url

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite

With apache in the htaccess I would like to replace all periods in the url only when there is an underscore after it.

I want `example.com?index.php/blog/low_vs._high` to redirect to
`example.com?index.php/blog/low_vs_high`

Can someone tell me how to do this?
Here is what I have, not sure where to go from here or how to properly debug. Thanks.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(.*)\._(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.(.*)$ /$1$2 [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this rule:

```
# execute when there are multiple occurrences of ._
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(.*)\.(_.*\._.*)$
RewriteRule ^ /%1%2 [L]

# execute when there is only one occurrence of ._
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(.*)\.(_.*)$
RewriteRule ^ /%1%2 [L,NE,R=301]
```

Comment: Will it replace globally? or one time?

Comment: Check my updated rule. Previous version was also replacing globally but doing multiple redirects. Updated version will replace globally but client will see a single redirect for better and fast experience.